# Remove duplicates from a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I need to remove *consecutive* duplicates from a list in Scheme for ex:

```
(remove '(e f f g h h e e))
```

should return

```
(e f g h e)
```

This is what I have but I keep getting an error:

```
(define (remove lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst '())
    ((null? (cdr lst)) '())
    ((equal? (car lst)(car(cdr lst)))(remove(cdr lst)))
    (cons(car lst)(remove (cdr lst))))))
```

I thought I was on the right track but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses are incorrect in the first case, and in the last case you forgot to write the `else`. Also, the second case is incorrect; this is what I mean:

```
(define (remove lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
    ((equal? (car lst) (car (cdr lst))) (remove (cdr lst)))
    (else (cons (car lst) (remove (cdr lst))))))
```